# Looking for the right way to combine concepts of (smart) investment and metadata

Tags: vocabulary

in simplified Chinese.
'investment' I believe is 投资
meta 元 as in metadata 元数据
The concept I am looking for in Chinese is 'making a smart investment based on (knowledge from) metadata'
I was told by a Chinese friend that 元投资 would not come across as being immediately clear to a Chinese speaker.
Any ideas?

Comment: More context would be helpful with special regards to metadata of what?

Comment: As in good metrics. The soundest investments are built on good data plus knowledge about which data are relevant and which are just noise.

Answer (score 1):

**"元投资" = "Metadata investment"**

I don't think "Metadata investment" is clear to people with English speaking background too.

For example the sentence you've used:

**"making a smart investment based on (knowledge from) metadata"** is not equivalent to simply as "元数据投资" or "元投资", its actually "making 投资(investment) based on 元数据(metadata)".

or the full sentence should be:

**"利用(using)元数据(metadata)去做(to do)有效的(smart)投资(investment)"**

I think the above sentence will make it way clearer to what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I think ***元数据投资*** is a proper one. 元 is the unit of Renminbi, it may mislead people, but 元数据 doesn't.